# Why insertText method is called with delay while scanning via Barcode Scanner

Tags: ios, delay, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make an App that take input from barcode scanner, now the problem is As we start the app, it works great but as Time passes the input coming from the barcode scanner is getting slow down as number of scan increases. I tried to debug this and found that, the Time interval between reading two character of a single scan is increases with number of scans.

Just Connect the barcode scanner via bluetooth with your device and give it 15 minute to continuos scanning. And See the Logs(Output on Console).

Here is my code-

I have a UIViewController and a UIView (displayView) on this UIViewController.

### DisplayInput.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DisplayView : UIView <UIKeyInput>

@end
```

### DisplayInput.m

```
#import "DisplayView.h"

@implementation DisplayView

#pragma mark - KeyInput Delegates

-(void)deleteBackward{

}

-(BOOL) hasText{
    return YES;
}

-(void) insertText:(NSString *)text{
    NSLog(@"Text- %@",text);
}

-(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

And UIViewController is-

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DisplayView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DisplayView *displayView;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_displayView becomeFirstResponder];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is Output when I started the app.

```
2014-01-13 12:01:02.359 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 1
2014-01-13 12:01:02.364 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 2
2014-01-13 12:01:02.369 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 3
2014-01-13 12:01:02.378 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.395 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.411 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.423 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.440 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.455 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:01:02.464 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 1
2014-01-13 12:01:02.478 Link[20147:907] Text Data -
```

I started the app at 12:01:02.359.

```
Printed 'Text Data - 2' at 12:01:02 - 364

Printed 'Text Data - 3' at 12:01:02 - 369

Printed 'Text Data - 4' at 12:01:02 - 378
```

And See the difference between two character of single scan is 5 to 20 milliseconds.

Now after 15 minute continuos scanning, see the output.

```
2014-01-13 12:15:07.039 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 1
2014-01-13 12:15:07.221 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 2
2014-01-13 12:15:07.399 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 3
2014-01-13 12:15:07.577 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 4
2014-01-13 12:15:07.768 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 5
2014-01-13 12:15:07.965 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 6
2014-01-13 12:15:08.224 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 7
2014-01-13 12:15:08.511 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 8
2014-01-13 12:15:08.786 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 9
2014-01-13 12:15:09.019 Link[20147:907] Text Data - 0
2014-01-13 12:15:09.245 Link[20147:907] Text Data -
```

After 15 minute, at 12:15:06 - 860

```
Printed 'Text Data - 3' at 12:15:07 - 399

Printed 'Text Data - 4' at 12:15:07 - 577

Printed 'Text Data - 5' at 12:15:07 - 768
```

Now See the difference between two character of single scan is 100 to 300 milliseconds.

### How can I remove this latency. Anyone help me out. Thanks.